# bash script that goes through pdf files and asks for a rating

Tags: bash, pdf, terminal, zsh

I want the script to open a pdf, prompt me to rate it, close it and open the next pdf. After I have rated all the pdfs I want it to go through them in order of rating, so I see those that I rated with 1 first and then those with the rating 2 and so on. There is a issue in the following script as it doesnt go through the pdfs in order of the rating but rather randomly. How could this be modified?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set initial ratings for all PDFs to 1
for file in Slides/*.pdf; do
    xattr -w rating 1 "$file"
done

while true; do
    rated=true
    # Loop through PDF files with the current rating
    for rating in {1..5}; do
        files=()

        # Collect PDF files with the current rating
        while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
            if [[ $(xattr -p rating "$file") == "$rating" ]]; then
                files+=("$file")
            fi
        done < <(find Slides -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pdf" -print0)

        # Sort PDF files by rating in ascending order
        sorted_files=()
        for i in {1..5}; do
            for f in "${files[@]}"; do
                if [[ $(xattr -p rating "$f") == "$i" ]]; then
                    sorted_files+=("$f")
                fi
            done
        done

        # Loop through sorted PDF files with the current rating
        for file in "${sorted_files[@]}"; do
            if [[ $(xattr -p rating "$file") == "5" ]]; then
                continue
            fi

            # Open PDF file
            open "$file"

            # Ask for mastery rating
            read -p "How well did you understand the content of $file (1-5)? " rating

            # Add rating to file metadata
            xattr -w rating "$rating" "$file"

            # Close PDF file
            osascript -e 'quit app "Preview"'

            # Set rated flag to false if any file is not rated 5
            rated=false
        done
    done

    # Exit loop if all files are rated 5
    if [ "$rated" = true ]; then
        echo "All pdfs rated with 5"
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: First: Instead of your `find` loop, try this one: `while IFS=: read file rate ;do declare -a "ratings_${rate# }+=(${file@Q})";done < <(xattr -p user.rating Slides/*.pdf 2>/dev/null`. Then you could use *nameref*: `for rate in {5..1};do declare -n arry=ratings_${rate};printf " $rate ${#arry[@]} %s\n" "${arry[@]}";done`!

Comment: it still goes through the pdf files in a order which I dont understand. Pdfs with rating 1 should be shown to me sooner then the pdfs with rating 2 and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash script for reviewing pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75635923/bash-script-for-reviewing-pdf-files).  Same question, same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

pdf_files=( Slides/*.pdf )

# Set initial ratings for all PDFs to 1
for file in "${pdf_files[@]}"; do
    xattr -w rating 1 "$file"
done

is_finished=0
while (( ! is_finished )); do
    is_finished=1

    tmp_pdf_files=( "${pdf_files[@]}" )

    for rating in {1..4}; do
        for i in "${!tmp_pdf_files[@]}"; do
            file=${tmp_pdf_files[i]}
            (( $(xattr -p rating "$file") == rating )) || continue

            # Remove the file from the list so it won't be processed again
            # on this pass
            unset "tmp_pdf_files[i]"

            # Open PDF file
            open "$file"

            # Ask for mastery rating
            read -r -p "How well did you understand the content of $file (1-5)? " new_rating

            # Add new rating to file metadata
            xattr -w rating "$new_rating" "$file"

            # If the new rating is not 5 then we will have to do another pass
            (( new_rating == 5 )) || is_finished=0

            # Close PDF file
            osascript -e 'quit app "Preview"'
        done
    done
done

echo "All pdfs rated with 5"
```

The problem with the original code was that on each pass over the files (`while true; do`) you were re-scanning all of the files after processing each rating level (`for rating in {1..5}; do`).  That meant that, for instance, after rating all of the files initially rated 1 you were immediately asked to re-rate any file that you had rated as 2.  The new code avoids that problem by removing files from the list of files to be rated as they are rated on each pass.

The explicit sorting of the files in the original code wasn't doing anything useful because you were already getting the files in ascending order by rating due to the `for rating in {1..5}; do` loop.